# Angular 2 firestore display data collection-->document-->collection--->document-->values

Tags: angular, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have this in firestore:

```
 users(collection):
      id(auto-generated)(doc):                     
                         tasks(collection):
                               id(auto-genrated)(doc):
                                                     Client:
                                                     Project:
                                                     Date:
```

So i want to display the data  like:

```
user1:
     task1:
          client:
          Project:
          Date:
    task2:....
user2:.
      .
      .
      .
```

With my code i can display all the users but i dont know how to get the users plus their tasks.
PS: email and uid are values after the key of user. and with this i can display tasks of one user if you see the method gettasks i want to change the static key in the doc() with a value of all keys
Thank you and sorry for my english.
the service.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
  itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
  tasksCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Task>;
  items: Observable<Item[]>;
  tasks: Observable<Task[]>;
  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection<Item>('users');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        console.log(data);
        return data;  
      });   
    });
  }
   getItems(){
     return this.items;
   }
   gettasks(){
   //this works when i use a key of a user but i want to use a variable like data.id 
    this.tasksCollection = this.afs.collection('users').doc("S1fAjCs5udebjeFnHyEJpyAV4Ls1").collection("tasks");
    this.tasks = this.tasksCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Task;
        data.idt = a.payload.doc.id;
        console.log(data.idt);
        return data; 
      });
    });
    return this.tasks;
  
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  

  <div *ngIf="items?.length > 0; else noItems">
    <ul *ngFor="let item of items" class="collection">
      <li class="collection-item"><strong>{{item.email}}:</strong> {{item.uid}} {{item.id}} </li>
      <div class="container">  

          <div *ngIf="tasks?.length > 0; else noTasks">
            <ul *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="collection">
              <li class="collection-task"><strong>{{task.Client}}:</strong>{{task.Project}} {{task.Date}} {{task.idt}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <ng-template #noTasks>
        <hr>
        <h5> there are no tasks</h5>
        
        </ng-template>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #noItems>
<hr>
<h5> there are no items to list</h5>

</ng-template>
</div>
```